# Modeling exponential growth with mixed effects

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, modeling, parameterization, growth-model

I'd like to create an exponential growth/decay model along the lines of y ~ -a * exp(-b * x) in R. I have been able to do this using nls(), but my dataset has repeated measures, so I need a mixed effects model.

I've read that glmer() should work, but I cannot figure out how to get it working. I know what the likely start parameters are: a = ~30, b = ~0.3. I know what the equation should be: y ~ -a * exp(-b * x) + (1|x). But I can't find examples of people using this package with start parameters.

This doesn't seem like the kind of thing that a reproducible dataset would be helpful for, but I could generate one if needed. I'm really just seeking guidance on packages and tech specs/syntax to get this working!